# TypeError: Object has no attribute

Tags: python, int, raspberry-pi

I am working on a program that will grab the temperature from a probe, and then put it into a google spreadsheet.  I have modified some code I found, and I am getting a error that I don't know what to do with.

The code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import glob
import time
import gspread
import sys
import datetime


#Google account details
email = 'email@google.com'
password = 'password'
spreadsheet = 'spreadsheet' #the name of the spreadsheet already created

#attempt to log in to your google account
try:
    gc = gspread.login(email,password)
except:
    print('fail')
    sys.exit()

#open the spreadsheet
worksheet = gc.open(spreadsheet).sheet1

#initiate the temperature sensor
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

#set up the location of the sensor in the system
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'


def read_temp_raw(): #a function that grabs the raw temperature data from the $
    f_1 = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines_1 = f_1.readlines()
    f_1.close()
    return lines_1

def read_temp(): #a function that checks that the connection was good and stri$
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    temp = float(lines[1][equals_pos[0]+2:])/1000
    return temp

while True: #infinite loop
    temp = read_temp() #get the temp
    values = [datetime.datetime.now(), temp[0], temp[1]]
    worksheet.append_row(values) #write to the spreadsheet
    time.sleep(600) #wait 10 minutes
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 52, in <module>
    temp = read_temp() #get the temp
  File "temp.py", line 48, in read_temp
    temp = float(lines[1][equals_pos[0]+2:])/1000
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I don't know what it is.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am relatively new at this.

Answer (score 2):

`equals_pos` is an `int` (that’s what `str.find` returns), so `equals_pos[0]+2` doesn’t make sense. `equals_pos+2` would probably do.

Comment: Thank you, that looks right.  I will run it again tonight.  This was very helpful.